# Capturing the XML Source error in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xml-parsing, ssis-2008

I am using an XML Source as a Data Flow Source.  If it encounters an error, SSIS will capture the "pipeline" error but not the XML Source error which is the more descriptive.

We use the OnError Event Handler for the data flow where the XML Source resides to capture the system variable error message, which gives the "pipeline" error. How can we get the system to capture the XML Source error?

Here are examples of the two errors:

> [XML Source [1]] Error: The component "XML Source" (1) was unable to read the XML data. Could not find a part of the path '\thefilepath\thefile.xml'.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "XML Source" (1) failed the prepare phase and returned error code 0xC02090E7.